# after sign an App with cmd get error "Installation error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES"

Tags: android, eclipse, cmd, certificate

I created a certificate from a basic android project with the normal files after creating an hello world Androidproject with eclispe. I used cmd line inputs from this website:

http://pavan2pyati.blogspot.in/2013/09/android-apk-generation-through-command.html?m=1

I now their are some mistakes in the code... You have to copy aapt and lib folder into platform-tools and also the dx batchfile. Futherelse I had to delete AndroidManifest.xml in the bin  folder before "Create APK file".

After all the signing process I get no error. But when I try to use BlueStacks Emulator to start my android App I get the error:  "install_parse_failed_no_certificates"

So I checked The file with jarsigner -verify -verbose MySecondApp.apk

And get following endoutput:

```
s       3508 Mon Jan 06 16:04:38 CET 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
    3670 Mon Jan 06 16:04:40 CET 2014 META-INF/MYSECOND.SF
    1443 Mon Jan 06 16:04:40 CET 2014 META-INF/MYSECOND.RSA
sm       660 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp /util/SystemUiHider$1.class
sm       307 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/util/SystemUiHider$OnVisibilityChangeListener.class
sm      2090 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/util/SystemUiHider.class
sm      1516 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/util/SystemUiHiderBase.class
sm      2066 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/util/SystemUiHiderHoneycomb$1.class
sm      2208 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/util/SystemUiHiderHoneycomb.class
sm       355 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/BuildConfig.class
sm       958 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/FullscreenActivity$1.class
sm       853 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/FullscreenActivity$2.class
sm      1991 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/FullscreenActivity$3.class
sm      1028 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/FullscreenActivity$4.class
sm      3067 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/FullscreenActivity.class
sm       457 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$attr.class
sm       415 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$color.class
sm       422 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$drawable.class
sm       498 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$id.class
sm       424 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$layout.class
sm       486 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$string.class
sm       605 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$style.class
sm       665 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R$styleable.class
sm       733 Mon Jan 06 11:59:16 CET 2014 classes/com/example/mysecondapp/R.class
sm      1444 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 res/layout/activity_fullscreen.xml
sm      1736 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 AndroidManifest.xml
sm    564412 Mon Jan 06 15:44:50 CET 2014 classes.dex
sm      2636 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 resources.arsc
sm      5964 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png
sm      3112 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png
sm      9355 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png
sm     17889 Mon Jan 06 15:56:58 CET 2014 res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png

  s = signature was verified
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.

Warning:
This jar contains entries whose certificate chain is not validated.

Re-run with the -verbose and -certs options for more details.
```

What could I do ?
I also heard that there is a chaninging on the website http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signapp
Which say:

Caution: As of JDK 7, the default signing algorithim has changed, requiring you to specify the signature and digest algorithims (-sigalg and -digestalg) when you sign an APK.

But I dont know what to change. I use the newest update of Android ADT

Answer (score 0):

What android version is in your BlueStacks Emulator. If it's android version is lower than your application version then is error raise.

Comment: I fixed it.I used    bin\jarsigner" -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore C:\